# A simple constrained optimization problem verification

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have the following minimization problem:

minimize $F=\frac{2-A\cdot x}{2(1-A.x)}$

s.t  $x_{min}\leq x \leq x_{max}$

Here is my approach with lagrange multiplier:

$L=F+ \phi (x_{min}-x) + \theta (x-x_{max}) $

$\partial{L}/\partial{x}=0$

So, $\frac{A}{2(1-A\cdot X)^2}-\phi+\theta=0$

$x=\frac{1}{A}\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{A}{2(\phi - \theta)}}\right)$

Now, how do I find the value of $(\phi - \theta)$?

Comment: You can investigate the value of the Lagrange multipliers by checking the [complementary slackness conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush–Kuhn–Tucker_conditions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think the function is minimised at $x = 2/A$? The numerator is zero, but the function itself can clearly go negative. Doing some rearrangement, we get

$$\begin{eqnarray}\frac{2-Ax}{2(1-Ax)} & = & \frac{1-Ax+1}{2(1-Ax)} \\
& = & \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2(1-Ax)}\end{eqnarray}$$

Which is clearly just a standard hyperbola with a bit of shifting and scaling going on. In fact, the function is strictly increasing for all $x \neq \frac{1}{A}$, so assuming that the given interval doesn't contain that point, then the minimum of the function will be at $x = x_{max}$.

You can check the logic by graphing it for a particular value of $A$, such as $A = 1$, [which I got Wolfram Alpha to do for me here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D(2-x)%2F(2-2x)).